# How to add Google fonts to Drupal 8 theme?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

What is the right way to add a Google font to a Drupal 8 theme?

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit `THEME.libraries.yml` and add it as a regular CSS file with "external" type:

```
global-styling:
 css:
   theme:
     https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato: { type: external }
```

Comment: Answer is fine, I've added also ```:``` after Lato, to make it key: value compatibile

Comment: I had to add `:` too, just as @cssBlaster21895 wrote. It would be nice if the answer could be updated to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to Maxim's answer, you can add a css file via libraries, and load your Google Font with the @import method.

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Hairline');